# Best content management system for a web hosting provider website?

Tags: cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

Which is the best CMS for a hosting provider website?

1. Wordress (Is this Not fit for websites?)
2. Joomla (low security)
3. PHP Coded pages
4. Drupal

Answer (score 0):

It depends largely on the content. In my experience, Drupal has been very versatile and easily extendable.  Drupal should be suitable, depending on your needs.

I personally don't like WordPress; I think it's over-hyped. I find it to be very insecure and poorly designed.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing isn't the category of site, it is the function the site is to perform.

Presumably you would want a news section, sales section and support section?

Any CMS would do it, the question is more about what skill set you have in house to be able to create and support the site.

If the hosting provider is also providing cPanel scripts to create various CMS, I would suggest you eat your own dog food and use one of them.